# Asp.net core web api publishing error using .net 6 in server

Tags: .net-6.0

I would like to ask one question relating to the .net core api issue.I am facing this issue as asp.net core api is deployed in app server.The other web portal is deployed in the web server. I am able to access to asp.net core api by browsing url directly it in iis browser. When I accessed it through webportal, I am able to call get/post methods which are not using through database something like getToken or greeting message. However, 403 errors encountered which are trying to retrieve from the database,

1. Deployed web api in app server
2. Request from web portal which is deployed in web server
3. Able to retrieve request/response the get/post methods - for example - getToken()/hello message (text) from web portal
4. Able to retrieve all requests the get/post methods (text or json) which includes json/text response through database connection/free text response
5. Not able to retrieve request/response the get/post methods - which includes json response throuth the database connection